# How to format text in php when we have 2 or more options

Tags: php, forms, text, formatting

I'm trying to make a simple script that allow formatting text and submit it.

Here is the form:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <title>
> </title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <form method="post" action="step2.php">
> <input type="text" name="text"  /><br>
> Red<input type="radio" name="Red" /> <br>
> 15px<input type="radio" name="15" /> <br>
> <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
> </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

and in the step2.php at this stage i'm showing results when 2 options are selected. **I'm trying to show results when only "Red" is select, when only "15px" is selecet, when both are selected and when nothing is selected.**
Here is my script for the moment:

> ```
> <?php
> if (isset($_POST['Red']) && isset($_POST['15']) ) {
> echo "<font size='15px' color=red>";
> echo $_POST['text'];
> echo "</font>";
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

**I succeeded**
Thanks for answers!
the secret was in **empty**($varname), here's the code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Red']) && isset($_POST['15']) ) {
echo "<font size='15px' color=red>";
echo $_POST['text'];
echo "</font>";
}

if (empty($_POST['Red']) && isset($_POST['15']) ) {
echo "<font size='15px'>";
echo $_POST['text'];
echo "</font>";
}

if (isset($_POST['Red']) && empty($_POST['15']) ) {
echo "<font color=red>";
echo $_POST['text'];
echo "</font>";
}

if (empty($_POST['Red']) && empty($_POST['15']) ) {
echo $_POST['text'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Why would you use `<font>` tag? Why not CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better way to do it is some XML/DOM tool

But you can use this code:

```
$attrs='';
if(isset($_POST['Red']))
    $attrs.='color=red';
if(isset($_POST['15']))
    $attrs.='size="15px";
```

Besides, you should know that `<font>` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

Radiobuttons should have the same name, otherwise use checkbox, and also better to use not numeric names for form fields

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="step2.php">
<input type="text" name="text"  /><br>
Red<input type="checkbox" name="Red" value="Red" /> <br>
15px<input type="checkbox" name="px15" value="15" /> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

step2.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Red']) && isset($_POST['px15']) ) {
echo "<font size='15px' color=red>";
echo $_POST['text'];
echo "</font>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :) :

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['Red']) && isset($_POST['15']) ) {
echo "<font size='15px' color=red>";
echo $_POST['text'];
echo "</font>";
}

if (empty($_POST['Red']) && isset($_POST['15']) ) {
echo "<font size='15px'>";
echo $_POST['text'];
echo "</font>";
}

if (isset($_POST['Red']) && empty($_POST['15']) ) {
echo "<font color=red>";
echo $_POST['text'];
echo "</font>";
}

if (empty($_POST['Red']) && empty($_POST['15']) ) {
echo $_POST['text'];
}
?>
```